# Lucee - header and footer is not coming into each page

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I am using **Lucee** to generate pdf. PDF has more than 1 page. whenever pdf is being generated then header and footer are not coming into each . It is only coming to last page of pdf. I have attached sample code also. I am not able to identify what mistake I am doing.
Any guidance will be helpful.

```
<h1>generating pdf</h1>
    
<cfdocument format="PDF" name="pdf" orientation="portrait" permissions="AllowPrinting" pagetype = "custom" pagewidth = "10" unit = "in" pageheight="10" marginLeft="0.25"       marginRight="0.25" marginBottom=".5" marginTop=".5">
    <cfdocumentitem type="header">
        <div style="text-align:left;">
            <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" align="left" width = "78" height="26" alt="Vitalware" id="logo"/>
        </div>          
    </cfdocumentitem>
    
    
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <style>
            <cfoutput>
            </cfoutput>
            td.mainBorder{ border: solid #BDBDBD 1px;}  
            td.showBorder{ border: solid #F2F2F2 1px;}  
        </style>
    </head>
    <html>
    <body>
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        <br/>
        What a two-page spread is
        A two-page spread is a printing convention that represents leading and trailing pages in a bound or folded project such as a book, booklet, newsletter, or greeting card. Often, the pages in a two-page spread mirror one another.
        <br/>
        For example, pages 2 and 3 of this four-page newsletter make up a two-page spread.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.<br/>
        What a two-page spread is
        A two-page spread is a printing convention that represents leading and trailing pages in a bound or folded project such as a book, booklet, newsletter, or greeting card. Often, the pages in a two-page spread mirror one another.
        <br/>
        For example, pages 2 and 3 of this four-page newsletter make up a two-page spread.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        What a two-page spread is

        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        <br/>
        What a two-page spread is
        A two-page spread is a printing convention that represents leading and trailing pages in a bound or folded project such as a book, booklet, newsletter, or greeting card. Often, the pages in a two-page spread mirror one another.
        <br/>
        For example, pages 2 and 3 of this four-page newsletter make up a two-page spread.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.<br/>
        What a two-page spread is
        A two-page spread is a printing convention that represents leading and trailing pages in a bound or folded project such as a book, booklet, newsletter, or greeting card. Often, the pages in a two-page spread mirror one another.
        <br/>
        For example, pages 2 and 3 of this four-page newsletter make up a two-page spread.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        What a two-page spread is
        A two-page spread is a printing convention that represents leading and trailing pages in a bound or folded project such as a book, booklet, newsletter, or greeting card. Often, the pages in a two-page spread mirror one another.
        <br/>
        For example, pages 2 and 3 of this four-page newsletter make up a two-page spread.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        <br/>
        What a two-page spread is
        A two-page spread is a printing convention that represents leading and trailing pages in a bound or folded project such as a book, booklet, newsletter, or greeting card. Often, the pages in a two-page spread mirror one another.
        <br/>
        For example, pages 2 and 3 of this four-page newsletter make up a two-page spread.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.<br/>
        What a two-page spread is
        A two-page spread is a printing convention that represents leading and trailing pages in a bound or folded project such as a book, booklet, newsletter, or greeting card. Often, the pages in a two-page spread mirror one another.
        <br/>
        For example, pages 2 and 3 of this four-page newsletter make up a two-page spread.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        What a two-page spread is
        A two-page spread is a printing convention that represents leading and trailing pages in a bound or folded project such as a book, booklet, newsletter, or greeting card. Often, the pages in a two-page spread mirror one another.
        <br/>
        For example, pages 2 and 3 of this four-page newsletter make up a two-page spread.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        <br/>
        What a two-page spread is
        A two-page spread is a printing convention that represents leading and trailing pages in a bound or folded project such as a book, booklet, newsletter, or greeting card. Often, the pages in a two-page spread mirror one another.
        <br/>
        For example, pages 2 and 3 of this four-page newsletter make up a two-page spread.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.<br/>
        What a two-page spread is
        A two-page spread is a printing convention that represents leading and trailing pages in a bound or folded project such as a book, booklet, newsletter, or greeting card. Often, the pages in a two-page spread mirror one another.
        <br/>
        For example, pages 2 and 3 of this four-page newsletter make up a two-page spread.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        What a two-page spread is
        A two-page spread is a printing convention that represents leading and trailing pages in a bound or folded project such as a book, booklet, newsletter, or greeting card. Often, the pages in a two-page spread mirror one another.
        <br/>
        For example, pages 2 and 3 of this four-page newsletter make up a two-page spread.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        <br/>
        What a two-page spread is
        A two-page spread is a printing convention that represents leading and trailing pages in a bound or folded project such as a book, booklet, newsletter, or greeting card. Often, the pages in a two-page spread mirror one another.
        <br/>
        For example, pages 2 and 3 of this four-page newsletter make up a two-page spread.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.<br/>
        What a two-page spread is
        A two-page spread is a printing convention that represents leading and trailing pages in a bound or folded project such as a book, booklet, newsletter, or greeting card. Often, the pages in a two-page spread mirror one another.
        <br/>
        For example, pages 2 and 3 of this four-page newsletter make up a two-page spread.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        What a two-page spread is
        A two-page spread is a printing convention that represents leading and trailing pages in a bound or folded project such as a book, booklet, newsletter, or greeting card. Often, the pages in a two-page spread mirror one another.
        <br/>
        For example, pages 2 and 3 of this four-page newsletter make up a two-page spread.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        <br/>
        What a two-page spread is
        A two-page spread is a printing convention that represents leading and trailing pages in a bound or folded project such as a book, booklet, newsletter, or greeting card. Often, the pages in a two-page spread mirror one another.
        <br/>
        For example, pages 2 and 3 of this four-page newsletter make up a two-page spread.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.<br/>
        What a two-page spread is
        A two-page spread is a printing convention that represents leading and trailing pages in a bound or folded project such as a book, booklet, newsletter, or greeting card. Often, the pages in a two-page spread mirror one another.
        <br/>
        For example, pages 2 and 3 of this four-page newsletter make up a two-page spread.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        What a two-page spread is
        A two-page spread is a printing convention that represents leading and trailing pages in a bound or folded project such as a book, booklet, newsletter, or greeting card. Often, the pages in a two-page spread mirror one another.
        <br/>
        For example, pages 2 and 3 of this four-page newsletter make up a two-page spread.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        <br/>
        What a two-page spread is
        A two-page spread is a printing convention that represents leading and trailing pages in a bound or folded project such as a book, booklet, newsletter, or greeting card. Often, the pages in a two-page spread mirror one another.
        <br/>
        For example, pages 2 and 3 of this four-page newsletter make up a two-page spread.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.
        <br/>
        In this greeting card that opens from bottom to top, the inside of the card is a two-page spread.

        The page sorter (the control at the bottom right of the publication window that consists of page-shaped icons) looks like this for both the four-page newsletter and the greeting card.<br/>
    </body>
    </html>
    <cfdocumentitem type="footer">
        <cfoutput>
            
            <div style="text-align:right;font-size:xx-small;font-family:cambria;">
                #cfdocument.currentpagenumber# of #cfdocument.totalpagecount#
            </div>
        </cfoutput>
    </cfdocumentitem>
</cfdocument>

<!--- <cfset getPageContext().getCfOutput().clearAll() /> --->
<cfset getPageContext().getRootOut().resetHTMLHead()>

<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=test.pdf">
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" variable="#pdf#" />
```

I tried providing a link from trycf but its not allowing me to use above code to run.

Comment: even if someone can point me how to add header and footer in each pdf page in LUCEE Then it will be really helpful.

Comment: Where are your closing `body` and `html` tags?

Comment: sorry I forgot to add. In actual application, the content of body was being calculated dynamically. It is there. I tried replacing the content with 4-5 pages of static html body so might have removed the hmtl and body closing tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an unnecessary `<html>` opening tag on line 26 of your sample code. Removing that seems to make the headers/footers work ok.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
            <style>
                <cfoutput>
                </cfoutput>
                td.mainBorder{ border: solid #BDBDBD 1px;}  
                td.showBorder{ border: solid #F2F2F2 1px;}  
            </style>
        </head>
        <html><!--- <<-- Remove this --->
        <body>
```